# csvsimple Vertical Header

Tags: tables, pdftex, csvsimple

I'm trying to create a table from `.csv` files using [csvsimple](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf). Here are the contents of my file:

```
Degrees,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90
Time,1.33,0.90,0.72,0.63,0.50,0.43,0.41,0.40,0.38
```

This is a table of unknown number of columns, but the row numbers are known. Is there a way to create a table from this in LaTex? The headers `Degrees` and `Time` should also bo bold.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You say that the row number is known. Where in the document is this piece of information stated? Separately, does each row contain the same number of cells? Put differently, is the number of columns a constant across all rows? I guess the items in the first column (e.g., "Degrees" and "Time") should be left-justified; how should the other cells be formatted, though: left-justfiied, right-justified, centered, or something else?

Comment: @Mico thank you for your comment. For the known number of rows, I meant that if there's a loop of some sort, I can hard-code the number of repetitions into the tex file. It is not stated in a cell in the file. Yes every row does have the same number of columns (I should have probably put it into the question). The justification isn't really a concern as they should be quite easy to change I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to loop twice over the file. The first loop is for counting the columns and the second loop is for setting the table.

The following code implements a new macro `\docolumncount` which takes the file name as first argument and saves the column count minus 1 into the second argument, here `\mycolumncount`.

This is used to set up the table:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{example.csv}
Degrees,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90
Time,1.33,0.90,0.72,0.63,0.50,0.43,0.41,0.40,0.38
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,etoolbox,array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\docolumncount[2]{%
  \csvloop{
    file=#1,
    command=,
    after reading={\numdef\mycolumncount{\csv@columncount-1}},
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\docolumncount{example.csv}{\mycolumncount}

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l*{\mycolumncount}{r}}
\toprule
\csvloop{
  file=example.csv,
  no head,
  column count=\the\numexpr\mycolumncount+1\relax,
  check column count,
  command=\csvlinetotablerow,
  late after line=\\,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, counting and table setting could be put into a single macro for convenience.

Answer (score 2):

Just set up a large number of columns; TeX doesn't complain if you don't fill them all.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Degrees,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90
Time,1.33,0.90,0.72,0.63,0.50,0.43,0.41,0.40,0.38
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\section{Good typesetting with \texttt{booktabs}}

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l*{99}{r}}
\toprule
\csvloop{
  file=\jobname.csv,
  no head,
  command=\csvlinetotablerow,
  late after line=\\,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
}
\end{tabular}

\section{Bad typesetting with rules}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}l|*{99}{r|}}
\hline
\csvloop{
  file=\jobname.csv,
  no head,
  command=\csvlinetotablerow,
  late after line=\\\hline,
  late after last line=\\\hline,
}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note: I used `\jobname` just not to clobber files on my system; change `\jobname` to the actual file name. The `filecontents*` environment is used for making the example self-contained.

[image]

Comment: This is a very clean solution, thank you @egreg!