# Is it possible to enter csv data into csvsimple directly?

Tags: csvsimple

I'm using `csvsimple` to turn a CSV file into a table. I would like to embed the content of the CSV file into the LaTeX source file itself. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{csv.csv}
\end{document}
```

where `csv.csv` contains, for example,

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

I'm thinking about doing something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{
1,2,3
4,5,6
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The easiest way would be using `filecontents` to write the data into the TeX source file, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246982/30617 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Thomas F. Sturm's comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{csv.csv}
1,2,3
4,5,6
\end{filecontents*}
\csvautotabular{csv.csv}
\end{document}
```

- `\usepackage{filecontents}` is needed to be able to declare the `filecontents` environment outside of the preamble.
- The starred `filecontents*` is needed to disregard the return character after `\begin{filecontents*}{csv.csv}`.