# Modify existing csv simple solution. Only 1st column left-aligned

Tags: tables, csvsimple

Can anybody help me modify the code below, from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292512/csvsimple-csvautotabular-and-csvautobooktabular-with-centered-columns-content) post in order to have only the first column as left-aligned?

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage{csvsimple} % For csv importing.

\makeatletter
\csvset{
  autotabularcenter/.style={
    file=#1,
    after head=\csv@pretable\begin{tabular}{|*{\csv@columncount}    {c|}}\csv@tablehead,
    table head=\hline\csvlinetotablerow\\\hline,
    late after line=\\,
    table foot=\\\hline,
    late after last line=\csv@tablefoot\end{tabular}\csv@posttable,
    command=\csvlinetotablerow},
  autobooktabularcenter/.style={
    file=#1,
    after head=\csv@pretable\begin{tabular}{*{\csv@columncount}    {c}}\csv@tablehead,
    table head=\toprule\csvlinetotablerow\\\midrule,
    late after line=\\,
    table foot=\\\bottomrule,
    late after last line=\csv@tablefoot\end{tabular}\csv@posttable,
    command=\csvlinetotablerow},
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\csvautotabularcenter}[2][]{\csvloop{autotabularcenter={#2},#1}}
\newcommand{\csvautobooktabularcenter}[2][]{\csvloop{autobooktabularcenter=    {#2},#1}}

% csv file from another question
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvautotabularcenter{\jobname.csv}

\bigskip

\csvautobooktabularcenter{\jobname.csv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `after head=\csv@pretable\begin{tabular}{|*{\csv@columncount}    {c|}}\csv@tablehead,` by `after head=\csv@pretable\begin{tabular}{|l|*{\csv@columncount}    {c|}}\csv@tablehead,` do the job, but I'm not sure it's correct to declare one more column in the `tabular` environment as there is in the datafile.

Answer (score 2):

As I said as a comment, you have to redefine your `tabular` header.

`\begin{tabular}{|*{\csv@columncount}{c}}` will make a table where the number of columns has been determined from your csv file, and all the columns are centered.
If you follow my comment, I suggested to add the first column as a left aligned one : `\begin{tabular}{|l|*{\csv@columncount}{c}}` but now, you have one more declared column in your header than in your csv file.
That's why you have to add a new counter wich s equal to the number of columns minus 1, which correspond to the other centered columns :

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % In the preambule
\newcommand\docolumncount[2]{%
  \csvloop{
    file=#1,
    command=,
    after reading={\numdef\mycolumncount{\csv@columncount-1}},
  }%
}
```

So, here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csvsimple} % For csv importing.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\docolumncount[2]{%
  \csvloop{
    file=#1,
    command=,
    after reading={\numdef\mycolumncount{\csv@columncount-1}},
  }%
}
\csvset{
  autotabularcenter/.style={
    file=#1,
    after head=\csv@pretable\begin{tabular}{|l|*{\mycolumncount}{c|}}\csv@tablehead,
    table head=\hline\csvlinetotablerow\\\hline,
    late after line=\\,
    table foot=\\\hline,
    late after last line=\csv@tablefoot\end{tabular}\csv@posttable,
    command=\csvlinetotablerow},
  autobooktabularcenter/.style={
    file=#1,
    after head=\csv@pretable\begin{tabular}{*{\csv@columncount}{c}}\csv@tablehead,
    table head=\toprule\csvlinetotablerow\\\midrule,
    late after line=\\,
    table foot=\\\bottomrule,
    late after last line=\csv@tablefoot\end{tabular}\csv@posttable,
    command=\csvlinetotablerow},
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\csvautotabularcenter}[2][]{\csvloop{autotabularcenter={#2},#1}}
\newcommand{\csvautobooktabularcenter}[2][]{\csvloop{autobooktabularcenter={#2},#1}}

% csv file from another question
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\docolumncount{\jobname.csv}{\mycolumncount}

\csvautotabularcenter{\jobname.csv}

\bigskip

\csvautobooktabularcenter{\jobname.csv}
\end{document}
```

Note : The operation on the column counter comes from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246803/csvsimple-vertical-header)